# Parameterization of one-sheeted hyperboloid to calculate surface area.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Let $S$ be a one-sheeted hyperboloid $S = \{x^2+y^2-z^2=1, z\in(0,1)\}$. Evaluate $\int_S z dA$.

I tried solving this in two methods:

1. By finding a parameterization: for each $z_0\in (0,1)$, the intersection of $S$ with the plane $z=z_0$ is the circle with radius $\sqrt{1+z_0^2}$. So a parameterization for the desired surface would be $r(\theta, z) = (\sqrt{1+z^2}\cos\theta, \sqrt{1+z^2}\sin\theta, z), \theta \in (0,2\pi), z\in(0,1)$. To evaluate $dA$:

$$ \partial _\theta r(\theta,z) = (-\sqrt{1+z^2}\sin\theta,\sqrt{1+z^2}\cos\theta,0)$$
$$\partial _zr(\theta,z) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}\cos\theta, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}\sin\theta, 1)$$

$$dA = \sqrt{\det
\left(\begin{matrix}
1+z^2 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{2+z^2}{1+z^2} \\
\end{matrix}\right)}=\sqrt{2+z^2}
$$
(We've defined $dA$ as the determinant of the Gram matrix of the partial derivatives of $r$).
And so we get: $$\int_SzdA = 2\pi\int_0^1z\sqrt{2+z^2}dz=\pi\int^3_2\sqrt{u}du=\frac{2}{3}\pi(\sqrt{27}-\sqrt{8})$$

2. By defining $\gamma (t) = (t,\sqrt{t^2-1}), t\in(1,2)$ a curve in the $xz$-plane, rotating it around the $z$-axis such that $r(t,\theta) = (t\cos\theta, t\sin\theta, \sqrt{t^2-1})$ is  a parameterization  for the surface of revolution, so $dA = \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}d\theta dt$ and then:
   $$\int_SzdA = 2\pi\int_1^2\sqrt{t^2-1}\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt=2\pi\frac{t^3}{3}|^{t=2}_{t=1}=\frac{14\pi}{3}$$

which seems nicer! But I'm not sure where my error is. Would appericiate any help.

Comment: How did "evaluating $dA$" result in $\sqrt{2+z^2}$ (times $dz\,d\theta$, I presume)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh yes! I've added the $d$s and I'll edit in my calculation.

Comment: Double-check the second computation, too.

Comment: I elaborated on the calculation of $dA$: the $i,j$ component of the Gram matrix is the inner product of $\partial_i r$ and $\partial_j r$. And where should I focus my inspection of the second computation?

Comment: You're missing a $z$ in your $\partial_z$ computation. In the second case, both your Gram determinant and your limits of integration are wrong.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the errors in your original computation have been cleared up in the comments. Here is a slightly different way to proceed. Notice that for the surface

$$\vec{n} = \nabla(x^2+y^2-z^2) = 3(x,y,-z)$$

with corresponding unit vector

$$\hat{n} = \frac{(x,y,-z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \frac{(x,y,-z)}{\sqrt{2+z^2}}$$

and thus we can rewrite your integral as

$$\int_S z\:dS = \int_S (0,0,-\sqrt{2+z^2})\cdot \hat{n}dS$$

Therefore, we can apply divergence theorem to the vector field $(0,0,-\sqrt{2+z^2})$. Closing the sheet off with disks at $z=0$ and $z=1$, divergence theorem tells us

$$\int_E \frac{-z}{\sqrt{2+z^2}}\:dV = \int_S z\:dS + \int_{D_{\sqrt{2}}} -\sqrt{3}\:dS + \int_{D_1} \sqrt{2}\:dS$$

The integral on the left can be done w.r.t. to cylindrical coordinates

$$2\pi \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1+z^2}}\frac{-zr}{\sqrt{2+z^2}}\:dr\: dz = -\pi\int_0^1 \frac{z(1+z^2)}{\sqrt{2+z^2}}\:dz$$

$$=-\pi\left[\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{2+z^2}^3-\sqrt{2+z^2}\right]_0^1=-\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

giving us the final answer

$$\int_Sz\:dS = -\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{3} +2\pi\sqrt{3} - \pi\sqrt{2} = \boxed{\pi\left(2\sqrt{3}-\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)}$$

or equivalently $\frac{2\pi}{3}(\sqrt{27}-\sqrt{8})$